# Rerun jquery plugin instance on window resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, centering, window-resize

I want to build a plugin that will be centerizing stuff for me, but I wanted to automate rerun every instance of it after window resizing, here's some (not-working on window resize) code:

```
$.fn.centerize = function(){
    var divWidth = this.width(),
        screenWidth = $(window).width(),
        margin = (screenWidth - divWidth)/2;

    this.css({'margin-left':margin + 'px', 'margin-right': margin + 'px'});
    $(window).resize(function(){
        this.centerize();
    });
}
```

All what I would like to do, is to run this plugin only once on some div elements, e.g.:

```
$('.myCenteredDiv').centerize();
```

And if I resize the browser window, it should recalculate margins and set new ones. I don't want to add somewhere additional code like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.myCenteredDiv1').centerize();
    $('.myCenteredDiv2').centerize();
    $('.myCenteredDiv3').centerize();
});
```

Is that possible? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with context:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    this.centerize();
});
```

Try to assign 'this' to another temporary variable:

```
$.fn.centerize = function(){
    var divWidth = this.width(),
        screenWidth = $(window).width(),
        margin = (screenWidth - divWidth)/2,
        _this = this;

    this.css({'margin-left':margin + 'px', 'margin-right': margin + 'px'});
    $(window).resize(function(){
        _this.centerize();
    });
}
```

Or you can try to use $.proxy for binding context in another scope:

```
$.fn.centerize = function(){
    var divWidth = this.width(),
        screenWidth = $(window).width(),
        margin = (screenWidth - divWidth)/2;

    this.css({'margin-left':margin + 'px', 'margin-right': margin + 'px'});
    $(window).resize($.proxy($.fn.centerize, this);
}
```